# Is such an iOS model possible to implement?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I would like to do the following:

1. Sell a game for $0.99 at launch with no feature restrictions.
2. If it's less than successful, make it free, but limit some features to in-app purchase (I would do this via an update to the existing app).
3. BUT, I would like users who originally purchased the app (before it was free) to still have all of the features.  In other words, I want to find a way to credit the new in-app purchases to those users, so that they don't have to pay twice.

I would like to do this all with the existing app, instead of making two separate versions of the app (paid and free).

EDIT: it is essential that not a single user ever have to pay twice (i.e. that users who previously paid for the app, do not have to purchase the in-app upgrades in the future).

EDIT 2: It seems like this question has already been answered here: [From Paid to FREE w/IAP: Preventing double-charging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365430/from-paid-to-free-w-iap-preventing-double-charging)

Comment: Have you done any research on this for yourself - read the Apple documentation, for example?

Comment: Yes, I have researched it on the Apple documentation and other sources.  My research thus far indicates that it is not possible to do without the possibility of some paying users having to pay again, so I went on a website called Stack Overflow to continue my research by reaching out to other developers who might have an answer.

Comment: Well, it would be helpful if you explained what you had found - we only have whatever you write in your question to go on.

Comment: That's a good suggestion; however, there are just so many less-than-ideal solutions that I thought it better to leave the question open ended than to convolute the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.

The company I work for has done this in the past.

If you know you might want to do this in the future, in your first version store a flag to `NSUserDefaults` indicating that the user has had the paid version. Then, on your In-App version check this flag and provide the content immediately.

If you already have a version released, you may have to look for something that you are already storing, e.g. the user has a highscore greater than zero to indicate that the user has already purchased the app. (There will be a small number of users that may have downloaded the app but not opened it and these users may be charged twice).

Comment: What if the user deletes the app and redownloads it again?  Then the preference would be lost and the user wouldn't be able to retrieve their paid status again.

Comment: That's true. Perhaps warn the user that this might happen if the app has changed from paid to free with a message the first time they open the free app.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  However, since it would be utterly unfair to make even a single user pay twice (I've updated the question to specify this), this solution isn't quite sufficient.  Furthermore, each paying user should have unrestricted functionality across all of their devices.  I suppose iCloud could help in this matter, but then again, not all users are signed up for iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is. Before you Update your app with FREE version, you add all users that have paid for it serial number "PAID"(or something), and everything else is just conditional statements(if-else). Congrats!